# D3 scatterchart highlighting all the dots that match a certain data criteria

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to highlight all of of the points on a scatterplot that match the id of the one being hovered. So far I have this function but it highlights all of the dots (or right now turns them black, but whatever). I need it only to highlight the ones that actually share the same id. can i use parentNode() on d to get the actual point and not just the data and build a new array of points and highlight them that way? Feel like maybe i'm missing a much more straight forward solution.

```
      dots.on('mouseover', function(d) {
          let dotId = '';
           let dot = d3.select(this)
            .datum(function(x) {
                dotId = x.playerId;
                console.log(dotId);
                return this.dataset; });

           dots.each(function(d){
              console.log(d.playerId);
              if (d.playerId === dotId) {
                  dots.style('stroke', 'black');
              }
            });
        });

      dots.on('mouseout', function(d) {
           //remove stuff
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, something like this should do the trick-

```
dots.on('mouseover', function(d) {
  var dotId = d.playerId;

  var matches = dots.filter(function(d) { 
     return d.playerId === dotId;
  })
  .style('stroke', 'black');

});
```

rather than building another array of elements you can filter the `dots` and modify the styling of the original selection.